# How to crop a shapefile in such way it follows a specific latitude in a polar projection?

Tags: r, r-sf

I would like to crop a shape file in such a way that it follows nicely a
specific latitude. For example, it is possible to `crop` this shapefile so
the bottom limit at 70N (near 60W) follows the latitude. I understand that
the `crop()` function uses a rectangle, so this is why I also tried
combination of `st_segmentize()` and `st_intersection()` whitout success.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.10.2, GDAL 3.4.3, PROJ 8.2.0; sf_use_s2() is TRUE
library(rnaturalearth)

sf_use_s2(use_s2 = FALSE)
#> Spherical geometry (s2) switched off

ocean <-
  ne_download(
    category = "physical",
    type = "ocean",
    returnclass = "sf",
    scale = "large"
  ) 
#> OGR data source with driver: ESRI Shapefile 
#> Source: "/tmp/RtmpUOEg4b", layer: "ne_10m_ocean"
#> with 1 features
#> It has 3 fields

bbox <- c(
  xmin = -90,
  xmax = -40,
  ymin = 70,
  ymax = 80
)

ocean |>
  st_crop(bbox) |>
  st_transform(6056) |>
  ggplot() +
  geom_sf(size = 0.2)
#> although coordinates are longitude/latitude, st_intersection assumes that they are planar
#> Warning: attribute variables are assumed to be spatially constant throughout all
#> geometries
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-06-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Could you show the unsuccessful results of `st_segmentize` and `st_intersection`, unless that's a distraction.

Comment: I basically transformed the bbox into a rectangle polygone. Then, I used `st_segmentize()` on it, so the polygon was not made from only 4 segments, but rather by a combination of smaller ones (I do not recall the length I used). Then, I used `st_intersection()` with this polygon.

Comment: I was just curious as st_segmentize calls lwgeom::st_geod_segmentize that uses great circle (on presumably unprojected long/lat) that generally seemed a good fit. Viewed from the pole, perhaps `sf::st_inscribed_circle` might serve your purposes. Then again, [sp - epsg 3995](https://khufkens.com/2017/01/18/r-polar-plots/), or something along the lines of `SOmap`, for the Artic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think `sf::st_crop()` will give you desired results, especially in context of S2 geometry. On the other hand `sf::st_segmentize()` will generally create segments following great circles, which is not what you want (great circles do not follow latitude; how could they?).

But I do believe that `sf::st_intersection()` is the way to go.

A dirty trick I have learned is to apply segmentization on a polygon with no defined CRS - and then transforming to EPSG 4326 already segmentized.

Consider this piece of code; note that I am using slightly amended bounds to exaggerate the effect (cropping at 74N instead of 80N).

```
library(ggplot2)
library(sf)
library(rnaturalearth)

ocean <-
  ne_download(
    category = "physical",
    type = "ocean",
    returnclass = "sf",
    scale = "large"
  ) 

bbox <- st_polygon(list(rbind(c(-90, 70),
                              c( -40, 70),
                              c( -40, 74),
                              c(-90, 74),
                              c(-90, 70)))) %>% 
  st_segmentize(1/3) %>% # segmentize first...
  st_sfc() %>% 
  st_set_crs(4326) %>% # ... define CRS second
  st_transform(6056)
                     
ocean |>
  st_transform(6056) |>
  st_intersection(bbox) |> 
  ggplot() +
  geom_sf(size = 0.2)
```

[image]

Comment: As with your 70N:74N, -90W:-80W really shows this off. Wow.

Comment: Thanks for your kind words! And on second thought - there is a great circle that does follow latitude quite easily; it is called the Equator :) it didn't quite click in context of polar projections...